# Start multiple SolrCloud instances in JBoss AS7

Tags: solr, jboss, lucene, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I already have a Solr instance running in my JBoss, with custom classes, config and so on.

Now, my next stet is setup SolrCloud.

I only found examples and help around Jetty, so, I have no idea about basically two things:

- Where should I put the zookeeper config file
- How to pass parameters to JBoss telling him where is the other instances (like [this](http://people.apache.org/~markrmiller/2shard4serverFull.jpg))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the parameters are JAVA_OPTS.

The easiest way to setup (single machine, for test/development etc.) is to use embedded ZooKeeper.

-DzkRun (enable zookeeper)
-DnumShards=2 (your number of shards goes here)
-Dbootstrap_confdir=$SOLR_HOME/collection1/conf - configures bootstrapping of zookeeper data. 
-Djetty.port=8080 (your port)
-Dcollection.configName=myconf (config name for zookeeper)

If you have several nodes, 
install standalone zookeeper:
use -DzkHost: instead of zkRun.
you may use script zkCli from solr scripts to bootstrap, or either configure -Dbootstrap_confdir ON ONE NODE ONLY.
The rest are the same

Comment: actually, I made it work some days ago.. `-DjettyPort` seems to be jetty specific, uh? Thanks for your help.

Comment: as far as I understand, they made jetty.port a global property, at least according to the mailing list